# Getting parse error on input ‘=’parser, even if my indentation seems correct

Tags: haskell

I am very beginner with Haskell, and I m trying to create some small algorithms to understand the syntax of Haskell,
I m trying to write and compile a quicksort algorithm, but it gives me an error at the compilation.

```
quicksort [] = []
 quicksort (x:xs) = quicksort small ++ (x : quicksort large)
   where small = [y | y <- xs, y <= x]
         large = [y | y <- xs, y > x]
```

Can someone help me to understand why I get this error at the 2nd line of my code.
`parse error on input ‘=’parser`.

Thanks,

I m also new at this platform so if I m not clear enough or I need to improve my question let me know at the comments.

Comment: Make sure the words `quicksort` align vertically. (second seems to the right by one; which is the issue here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intendation matters in haskell. I can reproduce you error with

```
quicksort [] = []
 quicksort (x:xs) = quicksort small ++ (x : quicksort large)
   where small = [y | y <- xs, y <= x]
         large = [y | y <- xs, y > x]
```

> .code.tio.hs:2:19: error:
> parse error on input ‘=’
> Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?

But when you remove the space before the second `quicksort`, it compiles fine.

Technically, you can use any intendation when you use `{`, `}` and `;`. **This is not recommended,** because you will have a difficult time finding the exact places where you need braces, and examples are rare. ("Rare" as in "endangered species" / "almost extinct")

```
{
quicksort [] = [];
 quicksort (x:xs) = quicksort small ++ (x : quicksort large) -- no `;` before `where`
   where {small = [y | y <- xs, y <= x];
         large = [y | y <- xs, y > x]};
main = print . quicksort $ "hello"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the problem was as you mentioned : the space before the second line.
Can you more explain why using braces ```{``` , ```}``` and ```;``` are not recommended ?
In which case that can be critical or can generate errors ?

Comment: @elfi it just looks bad

Comment: @elfi, I made a minor edit, inserted *because*. Furthermore, it took me a few tries to get the semicolons right, and I did not find resources where they have to go.

Comment: @Franky: It’s described in the [Haskell Report §2.7](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-210002.7) and defined in [§10.3](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17800010.3). Blocks always follow a layout keyword, such as `where`, `let`, `of`, or `do`, and semicolons separate the elements of the block, namely, the definitions in `let {…} in …` / `let {…}` / `where {…}`, branches in `case … of {…}`, or statements in `do {…}`.